# Webpack not accessible in Chrome/Edge Developer Tools

Tags: browser

I'm working on some webview pages and need to debug it on Android Emulator. When I open "chrome://inspect/#devices" in the Chrome Browser, I can find the emulator device which I use, then inspect the webview page I programmed, but I can't find the Webpack folder in the developer tools.

https://s3.bmp.ovh/imgs/2022/02/22b5d078b93d07e8.png

the strange thing is that I can find the webpack file by open the browser and type in my local dev url like: http:127.0.0.1:7000
like this:

https://i.bmp.ovh/imgs/2022/02/0cacb2fa243843d7.png

I have already enable the source map for JS in developer tool settings.

the application version:

**Android Studio** Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 20
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Chrome: Version 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: node version is v14.16.0